# How can I get a a list of the ESXi Versions using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, vmware

I am in need of getting a list of ESXi versions including Version Name, Build and Build Date.  I have found the information on the VMware site at : https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2143832

Using PowerShell:

```
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2143832
```

Returns:

> "Invoke-WebRequest unauthorized"

I am trying to get a csv file of the version table on the page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one. [Virten.net - ESXi Releases](https://www.virten.net/vmware/esxi-release-build-number-history/)

A JSON download is available and maybe it is possible to convert.